Replace a 3-way switches with occupancy sensor switches in a (4 way - 3 way - 3 way) setting
I have a stairwell that has one 4-way switch and two 3-way switches. I'd like to replace the 3-way switches with occupancy sensors and I need help with the wiring.
Box 1 Wiring(has neutral):
Was: 4-way switch with four wires(2 light brown and 2 dark brown)
Now: removed 4-way switch and spliced the like wires together.
Box 2 Wiring(has neutral):
Was: 3-way switch with four wires(1 light brown, 1 dark brown, 2 black)
Now: need help here
Box 3 Wiring(has neutral):
Was: 3-way switch with four wires(1 light brown, 1 dark brown, 2 Yellow)
Now: need help here
I'd like to install these motion sensors instead of the 3-way switches and I need help with the wiring.
Motion sensor switches has 4 wires(1 neutral, 1 ground, 2 black(interchangeable for line/load))
The answers on the suggested question doesn’t really explain how the wiring should work. All I’m interested is to get a wiring diagram based on the colors of the wires I have mentioned above

This question is similar to: How can I replace multiple 3 way switches with motion sensors?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes please? Also, do you have a specific make/model of motion sensor in mind?
